# laravel update runs well on my local machine but on the live server returns error "Creating default object from empty value"

Tags: laravel

i have this code which run very well on my local machine but on the live server returns an error "Creating default object from empty value", i have checked if the value is null but not.
what the piece of code does is if the value is not found in the database, create new one else update, the create works very well but the update does not work on the live server but works on my local machine.
the problem is on the else part of the program where $id >=1 and is this line  $ex->subject=$exams[$i]['value'];

```
public function saveExam(Request $request){
    if($request->id==""){
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Please select student']);
    }

    $exams=array_slice($request->exam,0,count($request->exam)-2);
    $class_rec=array_slice($request->exam,count($request->exam)-2,1);
   // return response()->json(['success'=>$class[0]['value']]);
    $data;
  $id=$request->id;
 $sess=settings_session::find(1);
 $session=$sess->session;
 $term=$sess->term;
 $id_num=0;

  $table;
  if($request->level=="primary"){
    $table="App\\exam_report";
    $id_num=exam_report::where('student_id',$id)->where('session',$session)->where('term',$term)->count();
  }else if($request->level=="nursery"){
    $table="App\\nursery_exam_report";
    $id_num=nursery_exam_report::where('student_id',$id)->where('session',$session)->where('term',$term)->count();
  }
  //else if($request->level=="pre-nursery"){
   // $table="App\\pnursery_exam_report";
  //}
  else if($request->secondary){
    $table="App\\secondary_exam_report";
  }
  if($id_num <= 0){
        for ($i=0; $i < count($exams) ; $i++) { 
         $ex=new $table;
        $ex->subject=$exams[$i]['value'];
        $i++;
        $ex->first_test=$exams[$i]['value'];
        $i++;
        $ex->second_test=$exams[$i]['value'];
        $i++;
        $ex->exam=$exams[$i]['value'];
        $i++;
        $ex->total=$exams[$i]['value'];
        $i++;
        $ex->grade=$exams[$i]['value'];
        $ex->student_id=$id;
        $ex->class=$class_rec[0]['value'];
        $ex->term=$term;
        $ex->session=$session;
        $ex->save();


    }
  }else if($id_num >=1){
    $exa=$table::where('student_id',$id)->first();
    $ids=$exa->id; 
    $id_it=$ids;
    for ($i=0; $i < count($exams) ; $i++) {
        $ex=$table::find($id_it);
        $ex->subject=$exams[$i]['value'];
        $i++;
        $ex->first_test=$exams[$i]['value'];
        $i++;
        $ex->second_test=$exams[$i]['value'];
        $i++;
        $ex->exam=$exams[$i]['value'];
        $i++;
        $ex->total=$exams[$i]['value'];
        $i++;
        $ex->grade=$exams[$i]['value'];
        $ex->student_id=$id;
        $ex->class=$exams[$i]['value'];
        $ex->term=$term;
        $ex->session=$session;
        $ids=$exa->id;
        $ex->save();
        $id_it++;

}

  }

  return response()->json(['success'=>'Success']);
}
```

it is expected to update the table but the error is on $ex->subject=$exams[$i]['value'] where $id >=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the problem is that on the database, the ids are not arranged serially, and each time i do  this

```
$exa=$table::where('student_id',$id)->first();
```

it picks the highest id, and when i try to add the next id which did not exist, i get the error, but on my local server, my database ids are arranged well, i don't know why this behavior, the solution to my problem is this line i changed

```
 $exa=$table::where('student_id',$id)->get();
    $ids=$exa->min('id'); 
    $id_it=$ids;
```

instead of pulling the first record, i get all record and find the minimum id

Answer (score 0):

Check all the data, collations, and names on the mysql remote server, check also the caps (in Windows the caps dont matter for tables, in Linux they do)